# Circuit python won't work send keys with (HID)

Tags: adafruit, adafruit-circuitpython

So when I push down on the keys that ive installed onto the pico they detected that its been pressed shown in the first picture.
[image: Keys detected]

Even though it has been detected it doesn't send the key presses that are in the code related to it. (Code shown below)

```
`import timeimport digitalioimport boardimport usb_hidfrom adafruit_hid.keyboard import Keyboardfrom adafruit_hid.keycode import Keycode
```

```
keyboard = Keyboard(usb_hid.devices)
```

```
Key assaignments
```

```
Top left
```

```
btn1_pin = board.GP19
```

```
Up arrow
```

```
btn2_pin = board.GP20
```

```
Top right
```

```
btn3_pin = board.GP21
```

```
Left arrow
```

```
btn4_pin = board.GP6
```

```
Down arrow
```

```
btn5_pin = board.GP8
```

```
Right arrow
```

```
btn6_pin = board.GP7
```

```
btn1 = digitalio.DigitalInOut(btn1_pin)btn1.direction = digitalio.Direction.INPUTbtn1.pull = digitalio.Pull.DOWN
```

```
btn2 = digitalio.DigitalInOut(btn2_pin)btn2.direction = digitalio.Direction.INPUTbtn2.pull = digitalio.Pull.DOWN
```

```
btn3 = digitalio.DigitalInOut(btn3_pin)btn3.direction = digitalio.Direction.INPUTbtn3.pull = digitalio.Pull.DOWN
```

```
btn4 = digitalio.DigitalInOut(btn4_pin)btn4.direction = digitalio.Direction.INPUTbtn4.pull = digitalio.Pull.DOWN
```

```
btn5 = digitalio.DigitalInOut(btn5_pin)btn5.direction = digitalio.Direction.INPUTbtn5.pull = digitalio.Pull.DOWN
```

```
btn6 = digitalio.DigitalInOut(btn6_pin)btn6.direction = digitalio.Direction.INPUTbtn6.pull = digitalio.Pull.DOWN
```

```
keyboard = Keyboard(usb_hid.devices)
```

```
while True:if btn1.value:print("Button 1 pressed!")keyboard.send(Keycode.SHIFT, Keycode.ALT, Keycode.L)time.sleep(0.3)
```

```
    if btn2.value:
        print("Button 2 pressed!")
        keyboard.send(Keycode.SHIFT, Keycode.ALT, Keycode.L)
        time.sleep(0.3)
 
    if btn3.value:
        print("Button 3 pressed!")
        keyboard.send(Keycode.SHIFT, Keycode.ALT, Keycode.L)
        time.sleep(0.3)
  
    if btn4.value:
        print("Button 4 pressed!")
        keyboard.send(Keycode.SHIFT, Keycode.ALT, Keycode.L)
        time.sleep(0.3)
       
    if btn5.value:
        print("Button 5 pressed!")
        keyboard.send(Keycode.SHIFT, Keycode.ALT, Keycode.L)
        time.sleep(0.3)
        
    if btn6.value:
        print("Button 6 pressed!")
        keyboard.send(Keycode.SHIFT, Keycode.ALT, Keycode.L)
        time.sleep(0.3)
```

I checked if I had all the need modules install and as far as I know I have them.

I would also like to mention that I am new to all this so I might not have something or haven't noticed something simple